# Провести математические действия над строкой

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит формулу для вычисления значения. В строке разрешены только простые арифметические действия и целые числа. Сложение, вычитание, умножение и деление. Язык С++. Примеры:
"1 + 1", " 10 + 5 * 100 / 5555" и тому подобные.
Видел давно, что такое можно реализовать через Boost.Python, но я без малейшего понятия.

Comment: Читайте про обратную польскую запись

Comment: Ну, берёте и пишете полновесный парсер. В качестве курсовой неплохое задание.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вот [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread289149.html) имеется такой готовый код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

// <цифра> ::= '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
// <число> ::= <цифра> { <цифра> } [ '.' <цифра> { <цифра> } ]
// 
// <выражение> ::= <слагаемое> [ ( '+' | '-' ) <слагаемое> ]
// <слагаемое> ::= <множитель> [ ( '*' | '/' ) <множитель> ]
// <множитель> ::= ( <число> | '(' <выражение> ')' ) [ '^' <множитель> ]

double eval(char *str);
double number(char *, unsigned *);
double expr(char *, unsigned *);
double term(char *, unsigned *);
double factor(char *, unsigned *);

int main()
{
    char str[BUF_SIZE];

    printf("Enter expression: ");
    fgets(str, BUF_SIZE, stdin);

    printf("Result: %lf\n", eval(str));

    return 0;
}

double eval(char *str)
{
    unsigned i = 0;

    return expr(str, &i);
}

double number(char *str, unsigned *idx)
{
    double result = 0.0;
    double div = 10.0;
    int sign = 1;

    if (str[*idx] == '-')
    {
        sign = -1;
        ++*idx;
    }

    while (str[*idx] >= '0' && str[*idx] <= '9')
    {
        result = result * 10.0 + (str[*idx] - '0');

        ++*idx;
    }

    if (str[*idx] == '.')
    {
        ++*idx;

        while (str[*idx] >= '0' && str[*idx] <= '9')
        {
            result = result + (str[*idx] - '0') / div;
            div *= 10.0;

            ++*idx;
        }
    }

    return sign * result;
}

double expr(char *str, unsigned *idx)
{
    double result = term(str, idx);

    while (str[*idx] == '+' || str[*idx] == '-')
    {
        switch (str[*idx])
        {
        case '+':
            ++*idx;

            result += term(str, idx);

            break;
        case '-':
            ++*idx;

            result -= term(str, idx);

            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

double term(char *str, unsigned *idx)
{
    double result = factor(str, idx);
    double div;

    while (str[*idx] == '*' || str[*idx] == '/')
    {
        switch (str[*idx])
        {
        case '*':
            ++*idx;

            result *= factor(str, idx);

            break;
        case '/':
            ++*idx;

            div = factor(str, idx);

            if (div != 0.0)
            {
                result /= div;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Division by zero!\n");
                exit(-1);
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

double factor(char *str, unsigned *idx)
{
    double result;
    int sign = 1;

    if (str[*idx] == '-')
    {
        sign = -1;

        ++*idx;
    }

    if (str[*idx] == '(')
    {
        ++*idx;

        result = expr(str, idx);

        if (str[*idx] != ')')
        {
            printf("Brackets unbalanced!\n");
            exit(-2);
        }

        ++*idx;
    }
    else
        result = number(str, idx);

    if (str[*idx] == '^')
    {
        ++*idx;

        result = pow(result, factor(str, idx));
    }

    return sign * result;
}
```

Если не хочется писать все руками - есть такие вещи как YACC или Bison.